# Winforms, BindingList, BindingSource - Cannot bind to property/column Id

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, data-binding, .net-2.0

I have the following code on a form:

```
Public Sub Init(ByVal SelectedItems As List(Of Cheque))
        Items = New BindingList(Of Cheque)(SelectedItems )
        BindingSource1.DataSource = Items 
        txtNo.DataBindings.Add("Text", Items, "Number")
        txtChequeAmount.DataBindings.Add("Text", Items, "Amount")
        lbId.DataBindings.Add("Text", Items, "Id")
    End Sub
```

This code gets called like so:

```
...
fmEdit.Init(myList)
fmEdit.Show()
```

All variables are populated etc, it seems to go through the DataBindings.Add ok but when the form appears I get the error about unable to bind to a property or column called Id.  I tried replacing the DataBindings.Add code to use the BindingSource1 instead of Items but I get a similar error.

The names of the properties in the class match that of the name in the Databindings.Add code.

Any idea?

Thanks

**UPDATE: Here is my class:**

```
Public Class Cheque
    Public Id As String
    Public Status As Byte
    Public Amount As String
    Public Number As String
End Class
```

Comment: What is `Cheque`? is it a simple entity? or is it something that might have a custom type descriptor somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example code, you show public **fields**, which are generally a very bad idea. Unless you try very hard (it can be done), data binding applies only to *properties*. So change those fields to properties and it will work.

IIRC in vb.net this is:

```
Public Class Cheque
    Public Property Id As String
    Public Property Status As Byte
    Public Property Amount As String
    Public Property Number As String
End Class
```

(but my vb is rusty)

or in C#:

```
public class Cheque {
    public string Id {get;set;}
    public byte Status {get;set;}
    public string Amount {get;set;}
    public string Number {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's how you do automatic properties in VB.NET. But do note that they are only supported by version 10 of the compiler. Since the question is tagged `.net-2.0`, it's very likely you're using an older version of VS as well. In that case, you'll have to write them out long-hand. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e8ae41a4.aspx) for an example.

Comment: I'm using VS2010 but its a .net-2.0 project unfortunately

Comment: @Jon - it should still use the 2010 compiler though, no?

Comment: I guess but I thought automatic properties were langugage version based rather than compiler version based ie/linq only available in .net 3.5

Comment: @Jon - the language version **is** the compiler version; it is the BCL that changes with target-platform. Auto-properties are not a BCL feature (unless you are doing everything in an aspx compiled on-demand)

Comment: I dont think I understand. I am using VS2010 with a .net 2.0 project therefore I dont have linq available. How will automatic properties work?

Comment: @Jon - automatic properties are just a compiler convenience that writes a field and the accessors for you; no more, no less - and certainly no LINQ involved. And as it happens, you can still use LINQ in 2.0 - LINQ is compiler tricks too. Sure, you don't have the "System.Linq.dll", but there are 2.0 implementations of LINQ for use with any compiler that knows the tricks; LinqBridge being the most obvious.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't implying LINQ has anything to do with automatic properties just that it was introduced along with automatic properites in .net 3.5 however maybe I have visual studio enhancements vs .net enhancements confused